# MailGun API Campaigns

Tags: mailgun

I am trying to create email Campaigns to use MailGun's stats tracking on emails i send. I am using the PHP library, and i am successful creating the first campaign using the following code:

```
$result = $mgClient->post("$domain/campaigns", array( "name" => "test04", "id" => "test04" ));
```

PHP Result Dump:

```
stdClass Object ( [http_response_body] => stdClass Object ( [campaign] => stdClass Object ( [bounced_count] => 0 [clicked_count] => 0 [complained_count] => 0 [created_at] => Thu, 24 Mar 2016 21:55:38 GMT [delivered_count] => 0 [dropped_count] => 0 [id] => test04 [name] => test04 [opened_count] => 0 [submitted_count] => 0 [unsubscribed_count] => 0 ) [message] => Campaign created ) [http_response_code] => 200 )
```

Then if I try to create a new Campaign using the same code changing the ID and Name:

```
$result = $mgClient->post("$domain/campaigns", array( "name" => "test05", "id" => "test05" ));
```

I get the following PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\GenericHTTPError' with message 'An HTTP Error has occurred! Check your network connection and try again.' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test_project\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php:136 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test_project\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php(90): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->responseHandler(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response)) #1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test_project\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Mailgun.php(80): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->post('mailgun.tekinfo...', Array, Array) #2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test_project\index.php(35): Mailgun\Mailgun->post('mailgun.tekinfo...', Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test_project\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php on line 136
```

Is there a campaign limit of 1 on free accounts?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, campaigns have been deprecated in Mailgun in favour of tags. There is no official statement on this, but:

- there is no-longer an entry in the docs for
  https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#um-campaign-analytics
- The user interface only supports tags as far as I can see.

This is a shame because the analytics pages for campaigns were much more powerful. However, there doesn't seem to be a limit to the number of tags that can be created, and one message can have multiple tags.